# How to declare an attribute of type "HybrisEnumValue" in items.xml in Hybris?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a use case where I am trying to declare a new itemtype with an attribute of type `HybrisEnumValue` inside items.xml.
However, when I try to do an ant build, I always get a build error on this attribute -  error due to missing type HybrisEnumValue.

This is my Items.xml entry :

```
 <itemtype code="xyz" generate="true" autocreate="true">
        <deployment table="xyz" typecode="1"/>
        <attributes>
            <attribute type="HybrisEnumValue" qualifier="def">
                <persistence type="property"/>
                <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true" />
            </attribute>

        </attributes>
    </itemtype>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HybrisEnumValue` is not a Type, its actually a interface which you can't define in items.xml as a object type.

To define enumValue in your model, you need to first define your enum values using `enumtype` tag.

```
<enumtype generate="true" code="ColorEnum" autocreate="true"
        dynamic="true">
        <value code="BLACK" />
        <value code="BLUE" />
        <value code="BROWN" />
        <value code="GREEN" />
</enumtype>
```

Its your choice to either make your enumType dynamic or not. Dynamic means you can add values at runtime as well. *Make sure your define enumType above your itemType.*

Check here [EnumType](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/SUP/Enum+Types)

Now define your enumType in your model like this ..

```
<itemtype code="xyz" generate="true" autocreate="true">
    <deployment table="xyz" typecode="1"/>
    <attributes>
        <attribute type="ColorEnum" qualifier="color">
            <persistence type="property"/>
            <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true" />
        </attribute>

    </attributes>
</itemtype>
```

Do ant all and it will generate ColorEnum.java which actually `implements HybrisEnumValue`.

Comment: Hi Shreshtt. thanks for your answer. Actually, I already have two different enums which has some common attributes. In a class, I want to access anyone of these. So I tried to define a single attribute which is parent of both the enums.